# Is it possible to have tokens that use tokens in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4, intellij-plugin, antlrworks

I'm new to Antlr and I'm trying to learn. I have a lexer with defined tokens. And another token that uses a subset of my tokens as so.

```
ADDQ: 'addq';
SUBQ: 'subq';
ANDQ: 'andq';
XORQ: 'xorq';
OP: (ADDQ | ANDQ | XORQ | SUBQ);
```

In my parser I have a rule called doOperation as so:

```
doOperation:
    OP REGISTER COMMA REGISTER;
```

When I test the rule using Intellij's ANTLR plugin. With an example: subq %rax, %rcx. I get an error that says, "mismatched input at subq, expect OP". What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do you use `ADDQ` etc. directly in any parser rules or do you only ever use `OP`? In the latter case, you can make `ADDQ` etc. fragments.

Comment: @sepp2k No for now it's just OP

Comment: @sepp2k I tried making them fragments also but I got the same error with intellij. For some reason when I try to run using command line with -tree or -gui I get a no method for rule * or it has arguments

Comment: Turning them into fragments should definitely fix the problem unless you're matching `'subq'` in other places as well. I'd have to see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to tell you specifically where the problem is. Regarding your attempts on the command line: That seems to be an instance of [this](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/229), though that should supposedly be resolved in recent versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use token rules inside of other token rules, but when you do, there should be additional text that's matched around it. Something like:

```
A: 'abc';
B: A 'def';
```

Given these rules the string "abc" would produce an `A` token and "abcdef" would produce a `B` token.

However when you define one rule as an alternative of other rules like you did, you end up with multiple lexical rules that could match the same input. When lexical rules overlap, ANTLR (just like the vast majority of lexer generators) will first pick the rule that would lead to the longest match and, in case of ties, pick the one that appears first in the grammar.

So given your rules, the input `addq` would produce an `ADDQ` token because `ADDQ` appears before `OP` in the grammar. Same for `SUBQ` and the others. So there's no way an `OP` token would ever be generated.

Since you said that you don't use `ADDQ`, `SUBQ` etc. in your parser rules, you can make them fragments instead of token rules. Fragments can be used in token rules, but aren't themselves tokens. So you'll never end up with a `SUBQ` token because `SUBQ` isn't a token - you could only get `OP` tokens. In fact you don't even have to give them names at all, you could just "inline" them into OP like this:

```
OP: 'addq' | 'subq' | 'andq' | 'xorq' ;
```

Another option (one that you'd have to use if you were using `SUBQ` etc. directly) is to turn `OP` into a parser rule instead of a token. That way the input `subq` would still generate a `SUBQ` token, but that would be okay because now the `op` rule would accept a `SUBQ` token.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I had to delete everything and start all over again the way you did it. I also think it also had something to do with the fact that I assumed a distributive property for ANTLR. For example something like:                         
(POPQ | PUSHQ) REGISTER won't give me the same result as (POPQ REGISTER | PUSHQ REGISTER).